# assigning linux capability to one java process

Tags: java, c, linux, execv, linux-capabilities

I run many java processes but I just want to assign cap_net_raw linux capability to just one java process. 
Currently if I do this "setcap cap_net_raw=ep /usr/java/default/bin/java" then this capability get assigned to all java processes.

After doing some research, I figured that I will have to write a c wrapper program and give above mentioned capability to that program and java process will inherit in execv. 
Another research says that capability can be assigned through systemd.

I am not sure how to use systemd capability option and if it's a viable option.

Can someone please guide me which way to go and how exactly to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a wrapper (using another stackoverflow article) to achieve this.

### capjava.c:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[]) {

  char  *cmd;
  char  **argvp;
  int ret = 0;

  cap_t caps = cap_get_proc();
  printf("Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
  cap_value_t newcaps[1] = { CAP_NET_RAW, };
  cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_INHERITABLE, 1, newcaps, CAP_SET);
  cap_set_proc(caps);
  printf("\nNew Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
  cap_free(caps);

  argvp = &argv[1];
  cmd   = argvp[0];
  printf("cmd is %s\n", cmd);

  ret   = execv(cmd, argvp);
  printf("\n return value of execv is %d\n", ret);
}
```

Now added permissions:

[root@localhost ~]#  setcap cap_net_raw=p /sbin/capjava
   [root@localhost ~]# setcap cap_net_raw=ei /usr/java/latest/bin/java

added capjava in systemctl config file for one of my application.